# Can we make this algorithm better?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, sweep-line

I am reading a book about algorithms and i think we can optimize the solution to O(n). I have attached the text from the book and my approach below. Can anyone please tell me whether my approach is right or wrong ?

> A sweep line algorithm models a problem as a set of events that are
> processed in a sorted order. For example, suppose that there is a
> restaurant and we know the arriving and leaving times of all customers
> on a certain day. Our task is to find out the maximum number of
> customers who visited the restaurant at the same time.
>
> For example,
> Fig. 4.7 shows an instance of the problem where there are four
> customers A, B, C, and D. In this case, the maximum number of
> simultaneous customers is three between A’s arrival and B’s leaving.
> To solve the problem, we create two events for each customer: one
> event for arrival and another event for leaving. Then, we sort the
> events and go through them according to their times. To find the
> maximum number of customers, we maintain a counter whose value
> increases when a customer arrives and decreases when a customer
> leaves. The largest value of the counter is the answer to the problem.
>
> Figure 4.8 shows the events in our example scenario. Each customer is
> assigned two events: “+” denotes an arriving customer and “−” denotes
> a leaving customer. The resulting algorithm works in O(n log n) time,
> because sorting the events takes O(n log n) time and the sweep line
> part takes O(n) time.

[image: Click here for image.]

**The algorithms says we can solve this problem in O(nlogn) and here is my code in c++ by which we can solve this problem is O(n)**

```cpp
    bitset<8> eve;
    // 1 for customer have arrived
    // 0 for customer have left
    eve[0] = eve[1] = eve[2] = eve[5] = 1;
    eve[3] = eve[4] = eve[6] = eve[7];
    int cnt = 0, best = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < eve.size(); ++i) {
        if (eve.test(i) == 0) {
            --cnt;
            best = max(best, cnt);
        }
        else {
            ++cnt;
            best = max(best, cnt);
        }
    }
    cout << best << '\n';
```

Comment: I don't think you've solved the problem because if you were given the input data as specified (a list of arrival and departure times), how would you construct the bitset in O(n) time?

Comment: I can create a bookkeeping array using a for loop.

Comment: Maybe you can write code for the complete task, and still see if you think it's O(n)? Or write out the algorithm in enough detail to be able to judge.